# Using jquery-UI Sortable, how can I drag a row onto a tables when there are no rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

### Summary:

I am using [jquery UI sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) with two tables (using connectlist) side by side and it works great except if one of the tables has no rows, I can't drag a row from the other table onto the "empty" table and I want to figure out if this is supported or if I need a workaround?

### Details / Code:

I have two tables lined up against each other (simplified example)

```
 <table id="table1" style="float:left;width:260px;">
       <thead><tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th></tr></thead>
       <tbody class=sortable>

            <tr><td>1</td><td>Name 1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2</td><td>Name 2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td>Name 3</td></tr>

       </tbody>
  </table>

 <table id="table2" style="float:left;width:260px;">
       <thead><tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th></tr></thead>
       <tbody class=sortable>

            <tr><td>1</td><td>Name 1</td></tr>
            <tr><td>2</td><td>Name 2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td>Name 3</td></tr>

       </tbody>
  </table>
```

and i have the following jquery UI Sortable code:

```
        $(".sortable").sortable({
            connectWith: ".sortable",
            placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
            helper: function(e, tr)
            {
                var $originals = tr.children();
                var $helper = tr.clone();
                $helper.children().each(function(index)
                {
                    // Set helper cell sizes to match the original sizes
                    $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width());
                });
                $helper.css("background-color", "rgb(223, 240, 249)");
                return $helper;
            }
        });
        $("#sortable").disableSelection();
```

and here is my CSS:

```
   <style type="text/css">
    .ui-state-highlight { height: 1.5em; line-height: 1.2em; }
    .ui-sortable-helper {
       transform: rotate(1deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(1deg);
       -webkit-transform: rotate(1deg);
    }
  </style>
```

If one of the tables happens to have no rows I can no longer drag a row onto that table anymore.  When I look in firebug i still see the TBODY there even if there is no rows so I am not sure what is going wrong?

### Update:

As Anton noted, this DOES seem to work in Chrome but not any other browser (and i need to work in other browsers as well)

### Update #2:

I got it working using display:block (and had to update some styling of my table).  My only issue now  is that the highlight row on these empty tables are not full width (my guess because of the display:block) when you hover.  here is a screenshot where you can see the yellow sortable hover is not full row.  This is not a blocker but it would look much better if it was conssitent with when there are rows.

[image]

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/xhMj8/ for chrome, but i just tested it in firefox and it doesn't work, seems to be a crossbrowser problem

Comment: Yeah, i have been testing in firefox and IE and doesn't work in either  . . any suggestions?

Comment: maybe the other browsers have problems to detect that you are in fact hovering a table? try to give the table (or maybe tbody) a `min-height`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a workaround for this that works for firefox and IE

```
        <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>Name 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td><td>Name 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td><td>Name 3</td></tr>
```

Create an empty `<tr>` in tbody

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xhMj8/3/)

**Update**

Found one more workaround

```
tbody{
    display:block;
    min-height:10px; 
}
```

and then you have to add this to the sortable:

```
            start: function(e, ui ){
                ui.placeholder.height(ui.helper.outerHeight()-10);
                ui.placeholder.find("td").css("width", ui.helper.width());
            },
```

but this will make the table look different

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xhMj8/4/)

You can add class if the tbody does not contain any elements like this

```
  stop: function (e, t) {
           if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
               $(this).addClass('test');
           } 
           if($(t.item).closest('tbody').children().length >0){
                  $(t.item).closest('tbody').removeClass('test');
           }
       },
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xhMj8/9/)

Comment: thanks Anton.  I appreciate the workaround but this solution screws up a bunch of my other code where i have jquery code looping through the rows and updating values (as now it updates values in this blank row and then it shows up)

Comment: Can you ignore the first row in the loop? Otherwise i found another solution. @leora

Comment: For the first suggestion, its not just about ignoring the first item in the loop because i also have css applied to table rows with padding etc so i can't seem to create the hidden row.  I am testing the display:block solution now

Comment: @leora ah, i see :/ I don't know any other way, i'll update the answer if i figure out something else then

Comment: @leora updated answer with one more workaround, which is the most viable imo

Comment: See my updated question (Update #2 section).  I got the display: block working but there is one aesthetic issue with the highlight place row (see screenshot).  Any suggestions on how to make that yellow highlight row full width?

Comment: Yeah, i updated it, so that the css display:block is only on if there are no rows in the table check the latest fiddle

Comment: which fiddle are you talking about (there are a few of them :) )

Comment: ok, i am a little confused now .  I am using your second suggestion (not the 3rd) to simply put a display:block and min-height on the tbody and then i specify width directly on my rows to avoid it squashing them.  The issue now is with the width of the droppable placeholder row that is displayed in yellow (which shows you where your row is going to end up). does that make sense? do you if there is a way i can specify this placeholder row?    in your example i don't see any background color on the placeholder so its hard to tell if your fiddle is solving the issue?

Comment: @leora I'm sorry, im not really sure. but i think that the display:block is causing the problem because it's squashing the td together. Thats why i think the 3rd solution might fix this

Comment: i figured out a solution using option #2.  since my placeholder is a TR element i have to change the TD element to be the same width.  once i do that i get the full width of the table

Comment: Here is the code:                 start: function(e, ui ){
                    ui.placeholder.height(ui.helper.outerHeight()-10);
                    ui.placeholder.find("td").css("width", ui.helper.width());
                },  I have added this to your answer and accepted it